# Find the value of the infinite product $(3)^{\frac{1}{3}} (9)^{\frac{1}{9}} (27)^{\frac{1}{27}}$....

Tags: products, infinite-product

[image]

I'm not sure if this is meant to be a contradiction but if a product is an infinite product it does not mean that the value if infinity? Or is the word infinite product just misleading.

I let:

$ (3)^{\frac{1}{3}}(9)^{\frac{1}{9}}(27)^{\frac{1}{27}}....=x$

If i cube each side: I get:

$(3)(9)^{\frac{1}{3}}(27)^{\frac{1}{9}}...=x^3$

If you notice you can rewrite the inside as:

$(3)(3^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}(3^3)^{\frac{1}{9}}...=x^3$

and simplifying the last part, we get:

$(3)(3^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}(3)^{\frac{1}{3}}...=x^3$

However, by substitution we have:

$(3)(3^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}x...=x^3$

$(3)(3^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}...=x^2$

$(3)^{\frac{3}{3}} (3)^{\frac{2}{3}}=x^2$

$(3)^{\frac{5}{3}}=x^2$

I got up to here but for some reason it doesnt look right.

Comment: Logarithm is your friend.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That seems like a good idea, but I want to warn that we're going into deep water trying to apply something like $\ln(ab) = \ln(a) + \ln(b)$ to infinite products. One must take care to show that the logarithm properties still work in the infinite case.

Comment: The "infinite product" in this case means the limit (if it exists) of a sequence of partial products.

Comment: @CaddyHeron: By the way, your approach didn't work because your ellipsis concealed the fact that the remainder of the products in your "simplifying the last part, we get" do not constitute the remainder of $x$.  What you actually have in that line is $(3)(3^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}(3)^{\frac{1}{3}}(3)^{\frac{4}{27}}(3)^{\frac{5}{81}} \cdots$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do all your work in the exponent:

\begin{align}
\prod_{k=1}^\infty (3^k)^\frac{1}{3^k}
    & = \prod_{k=1}^\infty 3^\frac{k}{3^k} \\
    & = 3^{\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k}{3^k}} \\
    & = 3^{\frac{3}{4}} \\
    & = \sqrt[4]{27}
\end{align}

The sum can be obtained as follows:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \sigma^k
    & = \sigma \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \sigma^{k-1} \\
    & = \sigma \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{d}{d\sigma} \sigma^k \\
    & = \sigma \frac{d}{d\sigma} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sigma^k \\
    & = \sigma \frac{d}{d\sigma} \frac{\sigma}{1-\sigma} \\
    & = \frac{\sigma}{(1-\sigma)^2}
\end{align}

When $\sigma = 1/3$, the sum is $3/4$.

ETA: As Arthur points out in the comments, this requires logarithms to hold in the infinite case.  In this instance, this should be fine because the logarithms in this case are all positive (so the series is absolutely convergent).

Comment: thank you so much, you are such a huge help. I just would like to know if i was given another problem involving infinite products, would logarithm always work or are there certain cases?

Comment: It's difficult to make a blanket statement about that.  The other problem I saw from you (regarding $(1+1/3)(1+1/9)(1+1/81)\cdots$) would not yield to that kind of analysis; the additions "get in the way."

Comment: I think I just found a nice problem for my calc students. Thanks for posting